# showModalBottomSheet with SingleChildScrollView. how to recognize when reaches end of the scroll in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bottom-sheet, singlechildscrollview

I have to display a bottomModelSheet. This bottomModelSheet contains Terms and conditions details and the **Accept Terms and Conditions** button(By default disabled) at the bottom.

When the user reaches the end of the scroll then I need to enable this **Accept Terms and Conditions**

So to achieve the above scenario I have used bottomModelSheet with SingleChildScrollView.

My bottomModelSheet code is below:

```
  mFormBottomSheet(BuildContext aContext) {
print(reachEnd);
showModalBottomSheet(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: aContext,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.90, //set this as you want
          maxChildSize: 0.90, //set this as you want
          minChildSize: 0.90, //set this as you want
          expand: true,
          builder: (context, scrollController) {
            return new Scaffold(
              body: new SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _controller,
                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Center(
                            child: new Html(
                              data: html,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0, right: 16.0, top: 24.0, bottom: 24.0),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: blue20Color)),
                        onPressed: reachEnd
                            ? () {   
                                  finish(context);
                                  setState(() {
                                    isItButtonClick = true;
                                  });
                              }
                            : null,
                        color: blue20Color,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("Accept the Terms and Conditions".toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),  
            );
          }
    );
  },
);
// future.then((void value) => _closeModal(value));
```

}

I have used ScrollController to find out whether the scroll reaches the end or not?

```
final ScrollController _controller = new ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller.addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_listener);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _listener() {
    final maxScroll = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final minScroll = _controller.position.minScrollExtent;
    if (_controller.offset >= maxScroll) {
      setState(() {
        reachEnd = true;
      });
    }

    if (_controller.offset <= minScroll) {
      setState(() {
        reachEnd = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

**reachEnd** variable becoming true when scroll reaches end however, **mFormBottomSheet** function is not getting called.

When I hot reload manually **mFormBottomSheet** function is getting called and "Accept Terms and Conditions" button gets enabled.

So how to invoke the **mFormBottomSheet** function when the scroll reaches the end.

Please find below image for reference. Onclick of checkbox I have to display modelBottomSheet. So this mFormBottomSheet(context); will not be called whenever the state changes. It happens only when I click on the CheckboxListTile.

[image]

```
                  CheckboxListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    checkColor: Colors.white,
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    value: isChecked10,
                    onChanged: (checked) {
                      setState(() {
                        if(checked) {
                          mFormBottomSheet(context);
                        } 
                      });
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` makes your widget rebuild. Do you call `mFormBottomSheet()` in your `build()` method?

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using CheckboxListTile to open the mFormBottomSheet(). So when the state changes this will not be called only when the user clicks on the CheckboxListTile() then mFormBottomSheet() will be called.

Comment: In that case, that's your answer then. (But I suspect you miss something, otherwise it wouldn't be called on Hot Reload...?)

Comment: In a real-time scenario, we will not have a hot reload. So the "Accept the Terms and Conditions" button should be enabled when the scroll reaches the end. And I should follow my designer's UI. As per the design, I should call the mFormBottomSheet only when user clicks on checkbox. How to solve this issue???